# How to implement the bulk deletion and bulk paste functions in the ag-grid?

Tags: jquery, ag-grid

I have a scenario that I want bulk copy something and then paste to the `textbox` controls of selection cells in a grid.
And I have another scenario that I want to delete all values by selection cells.
Anyone know how to implement the two functions?
It would be highly appreciated from your any feedback.

Comment: Bulk copy is the default feature of ag-grid. Just select the row you want to copy, https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php